# Gray folder with circle next to it

Tags: macos, finder, permission

I've got the strangest problem with some of my folders on an external drive. They folders in the root of the drive show up, but they are grayed out and I can't click them. However if I change viewing mode I can see the files that they contain. Any idea what this could be and how to fix it? I've attached two screenshots of the different events.

[image: In column mode]

[image: In list mode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tag without an assigned colour, and the contents is hidden due to the view options. Change the view options (⌘J) to Sort By and Arrange By Name.